# How to block ads in Safari without installing anything?

Tags: macos, safari

How can I block ads in macOS Safari 14 on Big Sur without installing any ad blocker extensions?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a DNS based Ad Blocker if you don't want to install anything on the machine itself.  For example, AdGuard provides free DNS servers that block ads.  You can configure MacOS to connect to that DNS server, and benefit from ad blocking without installing anything.

AdGuard DNS:  https://adguard.com/en/adguard-dns/overview.html

Comment: If you are a bit more techy, though AdGuard has some more features, Pi-Hole has a large community and is very customizable. I’d recommend pi hole if you’d like to tinker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /etc/hosts file to block ad servers.

Pre-configured lists are available at https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts and other sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Safari does not have any built-in ad blocking technology, apart from blocking pop-ups.

As far as I know, no browser comes with ad blockers preinstalled. Since no ad blocker is ever going to be perfect, requires a lot of maintenance, and may even have legal implications, I doubt it's something a browser vendor wants to invest into.

Comment: "no browser comes with ad blockers preinstalled."  https://brave.com

Comment: Safari comes with tracker and data collector blocking by default, as well as a malware blocker.

Comment: @anonymous: Yes, it does, but that's very different things. You still get to see ads and cannot block them with built-in settings.

Comment: @DarkDust yes, I agree with this. That is why separate extensions, such as uBlock and AdBlock, exist.